# How to run cdap datafusion pipelines sequentially

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I have a scenario where i have 5 pipelines which i want to run sequentially one after other. Is there any way to do this. I tried reading the documentation but it wasn't clear.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the blog post here -

Cloud Data Fusion does support chaining multiple pipelines together using event based trigger. Please take a look at blogpost here  https://medium.com/cdapio/event-based-triggers-for-cdap-pipelines-6f1c4b20adc3 which will walk you through an example use case for how to achieve that.

Thanks and Regards,

Sagar